# SonarLint: S2760 - possible bug

Tags: c#, sonarlint

SonarLint rule 2760: **Sequential tests should not check the same condition**

This hits on statements that run a method and is returning a lot of false positive.  The simplest example I can give is this:

```
if (_rnd.NextDouble() < Settings.RandomChance)
{
    MethodA();
}
if (_rnd.NextDouble() < Settings.RandomChance)
{
    MethodB();
}
```

The desired result is that sometimes MethodA is run, sometimes MethodB is run and sometimes both are run.

Comment: Just a note: As far as I can tell there's no guarantee that either of them will run.

Comment: yes, that too.  =)  -- Point being that Sonar shouldn't be flagging these types of items as the same.  It would probably be good to split it into 2 rules - on that doesn't check methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had some discussions on this rule already, which you can check here:

- https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-2760 in the comments
- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vs/issues/383

It seems that there are a lot of corner cases to this rule. We definitely don't want to maintain a list of exceptions to this rule, so our safest bet would be to disable the rule by default. I've created a GitHub issue (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarlint-vs/issues/419) for this, you could add more examples there.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted my thoughts over there.  I also now know where to look first before posting to SO.